# Templates are ignored

Tags: swagger-codegen

Description

I'm using my templates which are located inside `./templates` that looks like:

```
./templates
└───auth
    │   OAuth.mustache
    │
    └───living
            ILivingOAuthClient.mustache
            LivingAccessTokenResponse.mustache
            LivingAuthzCodeResponse.mustache
            LivingAuthzCodeValidator.mustache
            LivingOAuthClient.mustache
            OAuthzAuthzCodeResponse.mustache
```

Unfortunatlly, subfolder `mustache` templates are not generated. Only `OAuth.mustache`. Any ideas?

I'm using last version:

```
2.3.0
```

and I'm using this command line:

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i http://guest1:8080/authz/cmng/swagger.json -l java -c config.json -t .\templates\
```

Comment: If you put the other templates in the `auth` folder, does it work? What about if `living` is at the same level that `auth`, does it work?